# How to convert a string to an integer?

Tags: php

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=gb2312');

include("parser.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://www.souyishop.com/shop_gkq5/1280/products.aspx?sku=1351249&shbid=20358');

$price = $html->find('span[id=Product_main1_Label5]');
$price = str_replace(" ", "", str_replace("￥", "", str_replace("元", "", $price[0])));

echo (int)$price . "<br>";

?>
```

Basically, I'm trying to fetch the price ￥ 32 元  and I remove the currency and white space. After that I try to convert the string to int so that I can do calculation later. Guess what, I get 0. :(

Comment: What does $price look like before you do the `str_replace`s?

Comment: Casting as an integer should work if the string has been cleaned appropriately... have you done a `var_dump` on your string before casting to see if its what you expect?

Answer (score 4):

Somethign like this isnt going to work:

```
echo intval('￥ 32');
```

So try replacing all nondigits

```
echo (int)preg_replace( '~\D~', '', $str );
```

Comment: It is so close. Instead of 28, I get 1528. :(

Comment: I think you get 1528 because you have something else in that string. See my (updated) answer.

Answer (score 2):

That str_replace chain is cumbersome

A more elegant solution is to pull out all numbers with `preg_match`

```
$price = preg_match('/[0-9]+/i', $price, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Won't work.  `preg_match` returns [the number of matches](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), not the characters that match.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression in this case:

```
$re = preg_match('/(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
$price = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first echo `$price` without and int conversion to determine if you are actually replacing the string items you think you are, this is probably why it returns 0.

Chinese encoding requires special handling.

edit:

try using the html code for the char (yen = &#165;) see: http://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html

Comment: If I just echo $price, I will get the amount I want, let say 28. If I put (int)$price then I get 0. :(

Comment: OK, how about `echo (int)(trim($price));`